# logstashSend failBuild: true, maxLines: 1000 - How to not fail the entire build

Tags: jenkins, logstash, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, elastic-stack

I have a question about this line:

```
logstashSend failBuild: true, maxLines: 1000
```

I currently have this in a shared library, but I don't want to fail an entire build if logstashSend fails. If I set this to false, will it just move on and complete the build or will it throw errors? If I change to false, will I have to throw this into a try block?

Comment: Hi Patrick, show us your code, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this line of code:

```
logstashSend failBuild: false, maxLines: 1000
```

The [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/logstash/) says it clearly. If you set it to false the build won't be marked as failed.

> failBuild
>
> If checked, mark build as failed if this step fails.
>
> ```
> Type: boolean
> ```